# Looking to integrate/embed a chat client in a java webapp

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, chat

Requirements:

- Should be open source.
- Don't necessarily need to connect to an existing IM server, and can run my own so long as it can run in a Linux OS.
- Needs to support SSO with the app deployed in JBoss.
- Should be able to either skin the chat client to look the same as the app or better still, embed it without any borders or decorators.

Thoughts?

Comment: "java webapp"? Which one is running java, client or server?

Comment: Server. Building a JEE app and need to provide a chat service to all the logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample chat client with the Jetty webserver you can adapt.